# How can I fix the following Google Cloud Platform deployment error? [Error 2]

Tags: gcc, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy my web-app to Google Cloud Platform, and I got an error while deploying. I understand that last package (go-sqlite3) needs gcc compiler, and Google Cloud WM has it:

```
$which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

but it won't work

```
Step 3 : RUN go-wrapper install -tags appenginevm
 ---> Running in b0f03024342d
+ exec go install -v -tags appenginevm
github.com/mattn/go-colorable
github.com/mattn/go-isatty
github.com/labstack/gommon/color
github.com/valyala/fasttemplate/vendor/github.com/valyala/bytebufferpool
github.com/valyala/fasttemplate
github.com/labstack/gommon/log
golang.org/x/crypto/acme
golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert
github.com/labstack/echo
golang.org/x/net/context
github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install -tags appenginevm' returned a non-zero code: 2
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:926dc1a14e6f7eb5b3462b5c1d491aa6c73090291167ac2bf181c026b05f19da" failed: exit status 2
```

Comment: whats is output of echo $PATH

Comment: zer0xtgs@todo-hntu:~$ echo $PATH
 /google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin:/home/zer0xtgs/gopath/bin:/google/gopath/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/gradle-2.12/bin:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/google/go_appengine:/google/google_appengine

Comment: Change your path by giving this command & try again . PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

Comment: Does it work for you .

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your path correct by following command on your shell.

```
 PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have added this PATH to Google Shell Profile, buy it still doesn't work.        `zer0xtgs@todo-hntu:~$ PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
zer0xtgs@todo-hntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin:/home/zer0xtgs/gopath/bin:/google/gopath/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/gradle-2.12/bin:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/google/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/google/go_appengine:/google/google_appengine`

Comment: yes, it is the same error `# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
The command '/bin/sh -c go-wrapper install -tags appenginevm' returned a non-zero code: 2
ERROR
ERROR: build step "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker@sha256:926dc1a14e6f7eb5b3462b5c1d491aa6c73090291167ac2bf181c026b05f19da" failed: exit status 2`

Comment: Open github script looking for an gcc

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Ok change your path in .bashrc file of your home directory also.most likely your install script is opeining new shell which doesnt have path set. So set it  in .bashrc